# Let $V$ be a vector space and $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ linear forms where $\ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2 \cap\ldots \cap \ker f_n = 0$, then $\dim V \leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ linear forms such that $\ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2 \cap\ldots \cap \ker f_n = 0$, then I wish to show that the dimension of $V \leq n$. I am having difficulty showing that $V$ is finite. I know that considering a mapping
$T\colon V \rightarrow F^n$ where $T(v) = (f_1(v), \ldots , f_n(v))$ is injective, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hi! Is your first sentence what you want to prove? Can you make this clearer in that case? I first thought that it was just a comment, or something 'known'.

Comment: @M.Van edited to clarify.

Comment: Use the first isomorphism  theorem on $T$, and notice that $V$ is isomorphic to $F(T)$ which, in turn, is a subspace of $F^n$ which, finally, has finite dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T$ is linear and has trivial kernel, so ...

Comment: Rank Nullity only applies with finite dimensions. I'm not sure about your answer can you clarify.

Comment: You do not need Rank Nullity here.  A linear injection is an isomorphism onto its image in any number of dimensions.  Here the image is finite dimensional.